# how do i turn a whole file into uppercase?

Tags: ssh, putty, find-and-replace, vi, case

I have a file on a server on another campus that's all in lowercase that i need to changed to all uppercase. Is there any simple unix command that will do this? [i'm using PuTTy on a PC if that makes any difference.]

It's only 4 different letters (it's DNA, so just A, T, C, and G) so 4 separate search and replace functions would also work. (In VI or another text editor which will work through remote access.) but i don't know how to do a search and replace in VI?

I could copy it to my desktop, do a search and replace in a local text editor and then copy back, but then it would end up full of windows line breaks? [i'm on a PC, the remote machine is a linux server, and the program i need to interpret the DNA file can only handle unix line breaks.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to open the file in an editor you can use `tr` to (t)ranslate (c)characters ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)) directly:

```
tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be the VI solution. If you only want to replace those characters to the uppercase equivalent

```
:s/[actg]/\U\0/g
```

And for all characters

```
:s/[a-z]/\U\0/g
```

Explanation:
`s`(ubstite)
`[actg]` regular expression for those characters, or `[a-z]` for the range.
`\U\0` means: changes the matching pattern to uppercase
`g` replace all occurences

Advised reading:
http://vimregex.com/#substitute

Answer (score 1):

Im sure others will come around with more elegant solutions, but since your alphabet is limited to just 4 letters, you can just do this

`sed 's/a/A/g;s/t/T/g;s/c/C/g;s/g/G/g' <filename>`

if this works correctly you can add `> <filename>` or `sed -i ...` to save to the file

Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) for more info

Comment: is sed just a unix command?

Comment: yup, you should find it on any unix type system - my testing was done on a mac for example